# How to use generated Oauth 1.0 header for GET request?

Tags: get, postman, authorization, rest, oauth-1.0a

I have generated OAuth 1.0 header separately by using OAuth 1.0 custom header generator including following details.

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_token
- oauth_signature_method
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_version
- oauth_signature

My requirement is to trigger an GET request including OAuth 1.0

Is it the correct way to send GET request with Authorization header? header sample is below.

```
Authorization : OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXX",oauth_token="XXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1632196528",oauth_nonce="XXXX",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="XXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Once you generate a OAuth 1 header successfully, it can be used as a header under Authorization like following.

```
Authorization : OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXX",oauth_token="XXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1632196528",oauth_nonce="XXXX",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="XXXX"
```